# How to read line by line and execute operation in python

Tags: jquery, json, python-3.x, flask

Iam writing a python code to create a web service to ping ip address's and display result on web page.

Iam writing a flask code to ping ip address's and display them on same page. But, my code can only read first row and do ping job and display result on second textarea box.

can you say what iam missing in reading line by line from text file and do the job.

```py
from flask import Flask, jsonify, render_template, request
import re, os

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/_add_numbers')
def add_numbers():
    a = request.args.get('a', 0, type=str)

    def buffer_data():
        store_data = []
        var1 = str(a)
        with open("Bufferfile.txt", 'w', encoding='utf-8') as infile:
            for line in a:
                textdata1 = infile.write(line.strip(''))
            print("Done")
        with open("Bufferfile.txt", 'r', encoding='utf-8') as infile1:
            for row in infile1.read().rsplit():
                #print(row)
                # return(row)
                match1 = re.search("\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}(?:/\d{1,2}|)", row, re.MULTILINE)
                if match1:
                    ip = match1.group(0)
                    x = os.system("ping -n 1 " + ip)
                    if x == 0:
                        store_data.append(row + "--Active" + "\n")
                        #return (row + "--Active" + "\n")
                        print(row, "--Active" + "\n")

                    else:
                        store_data.append(row + "--Active" + "\n")
                        #return (row +"--Inactive" + "\n")
                        print(row, "Inactive" + "\n")

            #data2 = infile1.read()
            return (store_data)
            print("complete")
    return jsonify(result=buffer_data())


@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('test3.html')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="{{
  url_for('static', filename='jquery.js') }}">\x3C/script>')
</script>

<script type=text/javascript>
  $SCRIPT_ROOT = {{ request.script_root|tojson|safe }};

</script>

<script type=text/javascript>
  $(function() {
    $('a#calculate').bind('click', function() {
      $.getJSON($SCRIPT_ROOT + '/_add_numbers', {
        a: $('textarea[name="a"]').val()
      }, function(data) {
        $("#result").text(data.result);
      });
      return false;
    });
  });

</script>
<h1>jQuery Example</h1>
<p><textarea type=text size=5 name=a> </textarea> =
    <textarea type=text id=result>Get the result here!..</textarea>
<p><a href=# type=submit id=calculate>Get Result!</a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're only returning one row in your `for row...` loop.

Instead of return, you may want to append each row to an array, and return that:

```
def buffer_data():
    your_data = []
```

and replace both `return (row...` with `your_data.append(row...)`

Comment: that helps but, but when result is displayed on output textarea there is a "," beginning from second line and goes from there.. any sugestion? i edited my code after you said please go through it.

Comment: The edit is a little confusing, you should `return store_data` instead of `return (data2)`

Comment: Sorry, ya it should be what you said, my typo error. so, was do assist me now?

Comment: There's a few things you will need to look at now as there's nothing specific I can help with. Have a look at your input/output files, what is generated from `rsplit()` etc to find where the empty line may be coming from.

Comment: thanks, most difficult part you helped me out. i will figure it out.